# How do people make libraries cross-platform?

Tags: java, cross-platform

How do people make libraries cross-platform (UNIX-systems and Android, sometimes even iOS)?
What do they use?

I'm asking this because I make libraries as a hobby and I'm curious.

Comment: it really depends what the library does

Comment: The answer is going to be different for every library, which makes this an overlay broad question imo, but common answers include: 1) it's written in an inherently cross-platform language like Java or Python 2) it uses conditional compilation to call platform-specific functions in its implementation, or 3) it's built atop other cross-platform libraries and functions.

Comment: @jk: Not really.

Comment: Never heard about conditional compilation.
That's what I've been looking for! thanks!

Comment: In Java (the tag you used), writing cross plattform packages which do not need to call native OS specific code is very simple because the abstract layer, the java virtual machine, just disguises all (most) platform differences.

Answer (score 4):

**By using cross-platform languages, APIs and tools.**

Of course, all you're really doing is shifting the burden of responsibility, making compatibility someone else's problem (i.e. that of the language, API and tool developers).

Ultimately, someone, somewhere, needs to write a version of the code for each platform, even if that's only at the Assembly level.

In rare cases, that "someone" is actually *you*: when your lower-level base is not and/or cannot be portable, then you have to write multiple versions of your own code to support the target platforms. Usually you can do that without having to maintain distinct codebases, using conditional compilation, preprocessors, and so forth.

It's all about *abstraction*. Remember, abstraction is the entire purpose of higher-level languages!

Comment: And yes this answer is deliberately recursive w.r.t. the question. That's the nature of the subject. Hey, I named a base case!

Comment: Very good answer to a quite vague question. I especially like the "Ultimately, someone, somewhere, needs to write a version of the code for each platform" - maybe it could be bold too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for java:

the fewer dependencies to other jar-libs your lib has the more likely it is that it is crossplatform. All used jar-libs  must also be available on your target system.

if your lib has dependendencies to

- os-specific classes like `android.*` or
- gui specific classes like `javax.swing.*`

it is unlikely that it is cross platform.